# Integers not converting to strings not converting to strings(python)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, int

It seems that my code isn't converting integers in a list to strings. Here is the are of my code with the problem:

```
def aidrawboard(aiboard):
    for i in aiboard:
        inttostr = aiboard[i]
        str(inttostr)
        aiboard[i] = inttostr
        for i in aiboard:
            if aiboard[i] == '3':
                aiboard[i] = '0'
            break
    print(aiboard)
    print("THIS IS THE AI BOARD")
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + aiboard[7] + ' | ' + aiboard[8] + ' | ' + aiboard[9])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + aiboard[4] + ' | ' + aiboard[5] + ' | ' + aiboard[6])
    print('   |   |')
    print('-----------')
    print('   |   |')
    print(' ' + aiboard[1] + ' | ' + aiboard[2] + ' | ' + aiboard[3])
    print('   |   |')
```

The code is for a battleship game. an example of list aiboard is [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

I get the error "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly", with the error pointing to

```
print(' ' + aiboard[7] + ' | ' + aiboard[8] + ' | ' + aiboard[9])
```

Sorry if the error is very newbish. This is my first year coding.

Comment: `str()` returns a string, it doesn't convert an into to a string inplace.

Answer (score 4):

Since the items stored inside the abiword list are integers, you need to convert the datatype of  element (*you want to print*) to string while printing.

```
print(' ' + str(aiboard[7]) + ' | ' + str(aiboard[8]) + ' | ' + str(aiboard[9]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or may you can define a function to print_out the board:

```
def print_board(aiboard):
  str_state = map(str, aiboard)
  print('   |   |')
  print(' ' + str_state[7] + ' | ' + str_state[8] + ' | ' + str_state[9])
  print('   |   |')
  print('-----------')
  print('   |   |')
  print(' ' + str_state[4] + ' | ' + str_state[5] + ' | ' + str_state[6])
  print('   |   |')
  print('-----------')
  print('   |   |')
  print(' ' + str_state[1] + ' | ' + str_state[2] + ' | ' + str_state[3])
  print('   |   |')
```

In this way, easy to read and maintenance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never set the variable `inttostr` to the string you create. In your code

```
for i in aiboard:
        inttostr = aiboard[i]
        str(inttostr)
        aiboard[i] = inttostr
```

`inttostr` remains an int. A couple of ways to fix this.

```
for i in aiboard:
        inttostr = aiboard[i]
        inttostr= str(inttostr)
        aiboard[i] = inttostr
```

or better yet:

```
for i in aiboard:
        aiboard[i]= str(aiboard[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

A Pythonic way to convert is:

```
aiboard_str = [str(i) for i in aiboard]
```

Now print the board as before.